# Saving Infopath data to multiple list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am exploring options to build a form that allows to save InfoPath form data to multiple lists , i tried to do achive this using "Webservice Submit/ UpdateListItems" option explained in this blog(and other similar blogs) http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/submitting-data-to-sharepoint-2010-list.html
I can save the data that's simple but when trying to save data that involves lookup columns or other controls it was difficult to find the correct CAML syntax to update the lookup columns or showing dropdown controls, below XML template by default creates textbox control on the form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >?
<Batch>
<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
     <Field Name='Title' />
     <Field Name="EmployeeAddress" />
     <Field Name="EmployeeNo" />
     <Field Name="EmployeeEmail" />
</Method>
</Batch>
```

I cannot use code behind because Infopath with code is no supported by SharePoint online. And this template always creates textbox on the form, is there a way to choose the controls like Employee Address as textbox but  Employee Number as dropdown? And how we enforce validation on the controls created by XML template?

Lastly which one is better option to go when building forms for SharePOint online

1. POwer Apps (Convoluted procedure to replicate repeated section/
   tables).
2. InfoPath Forms ( convoluted procedure to save data on
   multiple lists).
3. Custom forms (using SPX) - has anyone tried this
   for complex list form?

Apologies for the length of the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom form using HTML+jQuery Plugin+Bootstrap, then submit data into SharePoint list using REST API. The following articles for your reference:

[sp-forms](https://github.com/michaelsoriano/sp-forms)

[CRUD Operation On List Items Using REST API Services In SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

Comment: How complex(time& effort) is it to replicate the repeated table / section and OOTB functionalities that InfoPath offers in custom forms?